# CentOS time jumps every microsecond

Tags: centos, time

It's a very strange thing. If I run this shell script on the server CentOS 5 (32 bits).

time.sh

```
    #!/bin/bash    
    for i in {1..10}
    do
    NOW=$(date +"%M:%S")
    echo "$i $NOW"
    done
```

The result is

```
    1 05:27    
    2 05:09
    3 05:27
    4 05:09
    5 05:27
    6 05:09
    7 05:27
    8 05:09
    9 05:27
    10 05:09
```

You see the time changes every microsecond.
I don't know what the problem is.

I run the script on another server. The result is OK.

```
    1 52:58
    2 52:58    
    3 52:58
    4 52:58
    5 52:58
    6 52:58
    7 52:58
    8 52:58
    9 52:58
    10 52:58
```